# Problem with java.lang.RuntimeException: setDataSource failed: status = 0x80000000

Tags: java, android, mediametadataretriever

I have a problem sending music images from the list

[image]

Hello, good time everyone
I'm making a music player and I'm having trouble getting the music image from the vote list
I have been struggling with this for 3 days, if anyone has any information, please help me

[image: img2]

[image: img2]

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of textual information like code and error messages. Post them as code formatted text. And when you do, make sure to post the entire stacktrace.